# Insert or Update a row in a group based on another group

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following table

| Group | Date | SecondGroup | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 2020-01-08 | A | 22 |
| 1 | 2020-01-09 | A | 7 |
| 1 | 2020-01-10 | A | 12 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 2020-01-03 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 2020-01-10 | B | 6 |
| 2 | 2020-01-12 | B | 14 |
| .... | .... | .... | .... |

I want to insert the Value 0 for each Group to the Date before the lowest Date of the SecondGroup
I want to solve this without using cursors.
I prefer not to use CTE either.

Update the already existing date row in the Group could also be a solution.

Result i want to achieve

| Group | Date | SecondGroup | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 | A | 0 |
| 1 | 2020-01-08 | A | 22 |
| 1 | 2020-01-09 | A | 7 |
| 1 | 2020-01-10 | A | 12 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 2020-01-03 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 2020-01-03 | B | 0 |
| 2 | 2020-01-10 | B | 6 |
| 2 | 2020-01-12 | B | 14 |
| .... | .... | .... | .... |

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not complete.  For instance:

- Do you really want just the maximum `NULL` date?
- What happens when there are multiple secondary groups?
- What if there are `NULL` values between the secondary groups?

Assuming that you really want one row per `group`, then one method is:

```
select group, prev_date, group, 0 as value
from (select t.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by group order by date) as prev_date,
             row_number() over (partition by group, (case when secondgroup is null then 1 else 0 end) order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where secondgroup is not null and seqnum = 1;
```

You can use `insert` or `union all` to combine with your existing data.

This version can be tweaked if your definition is a little different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your task clearly, but maybe something like this:

```
drop table if exists #t
go
CREATE TABLE #t(
    [Group] [int] NULL,
    [Date] [date] NULL,
    [SecondGroup] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](50) NULL
) 

insert into #t
values
(1, '2020-01-01',   NULL,   NULL),
(1, '2020-01-02',   NULL,   NULL),
(1, '2020-01-08',   'A',    22),
(1, '2020-01-09',   'A',    7),
(1, '2020-01-10',   'A',    12),
(2, '2020-01-01',   NULL,   NULL),
(2, '2020-01-01',   NULL,   NULL),
(2, '2020-01-03',   NULL,   NULL),
(2, '2020-01-10',   'B',    6),
(2, '2020-01-12',   'B',    14)


  insert into #t
  select 
  [Group]
  ,max([Date])
  ,(select max(SecondGroup) from #t t2 where t2.[Group] = t.[Group] and SecondGroup is not null)
  ,0
  from #t t
  where [SecondGroup] is null
  group by [Group]


  select * from #t
  order by [Group], [Date], [SecondGroup]
```